# ExpressJs route module which can handle controllers in different directories

Tags: node.js, express

Can someone suggest how can I implement routes for 'admin' controllers in 'admin' folder. Is there any good module to handle such routes with ease ?

Answer (score 0):

Require the correct .js file

```
var admin = require("./routes/admin.js");
```

Handle the route:

```
app.get("/admin", admin.load); //or whatever your export method is.
```